# apending html loaded via ajax to bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, json

Im loading some html from a database (method on a c# controller) and trying to display it inside a bootstrap modal body, but its always displaying as encoded.

In my c# method, I load the html from the db and html decode it before sending back in a json response like this:

```
response.terms.Terms = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(response.terms.Terms);
return Json(response.terms, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Client side I read the data and display like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  url: urlTerms,
  data: {
    role
  },
  error: function(response) {
    $("#ajaxindicator").hide();

  },
  success: function(response) {
    $("#ajaxindicator").hide();

    htmlData = response.Terms;
    infoModal.find('.modal-body-scroll').html(htmlData);
    infoModal.modal('show');
  }
});
```

when the modal window displays, I get this

```
%3Cdiv%20style%3D%22text-align%3A%20center%3B%22%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D%22font-size%3A%20xx-large%3B%22%3EThis%20is%20a%20test%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E
```

its not being displayed as html, can anyone tell me where Im going wrong ?

Comment: Place a breakpoint on `response` then check the value for terms before you decode anything. Let me know what it says

Answer (score 0):

It appears your `data` is encoded. You can use `decodeURIComponent()` to decode it...

`var data = decodeURIComponent(response);`

Here are two `divs` with the decoded data inside them.

One utilises `html()` and the other `text()`.

```js
var response = '%3Cp%20style%3D%22text-align%3A%20center%3B%22%3E%3Cfont%20size%3D%227%22%3Ethi%20is%20a%20test%3C%2Ffont%3E%3C%2Fp%3E';

var data = decodeURIComponent(response);

$('#fake-modal').text(data);
$('#fake-modal2').html(data);
```

```css
#fake-modal {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 470px;
}

#fake-modal2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="fake-modal"></div>
  <div id="fake-modal2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, ive added this htmlData = JSON.parse(response.Terms); but now the modal is blank

Comment: Is the data you get back definitely JSON?

Comment: Try just decoding `response` on it's own, then access the terms?: `htmlData = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: tried this   htmlData = JSON.parse(response); and then accessed Terms but the modal is still blank

Comment: What do you get if you console log `htmlData` from  `htmlData = JSON.parse(response);` ?

Comment: Would be good to see the raw output console logged too.. so without the json.parse ?

Comment: this messsage SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160297/discussion-between-proevilz-and-proteus).